# How can I bind scope variables stored in a .resx file in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Currently I am working on a ASP .Net MVC project using angularjs where I need to instanciate a variable with a value stored in a .resx file which contains
a static string and angularjs scope variables which are binded to specific values in the controller. Below is the HTML and respective code :

Here is the HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">


  <div>
     {{myvariable = '@Resource.Value' }}

  </div>

  <div>
       {{fullName}}

  </div>


</div>
```

where Resource.Value is a string contained in a .resx file with the following content:

> ' The First Name and  Last Name is :' + LastName  FirstName

Here is the angular controller:

```
function myCtrl($scope) {

      $scope.LastName = 'Boxer';
      $scope.FirstName = 'Jack';


     $scope.fullName  =  $scope.myvariable;

}
```

Here the result of `fullName` becomes : "The First Name and Last Name is : null null"

but the expected result should be : "The First Name and Last Name is : Boxer Jack"

How can I accomplish the expected result "The First Name and  Last Name is : Boxer Jack"

Any help will appreciated.

Note : I need to accomplish this because I am using locale resources files for different languages use and I need to display templated messages which its content can change dinamically

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you set `myVariable` the resource should become a string value in javascript.  So this:

```
{{myvariable = @Resource.Value }}
```

would become this:

```
{{myvariable = '@Resource.Value' }}
```